# How do I display the 'field' in mysql on website as table PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

how do I display mysql "field" column only on my website using PHP and SQL? I don't want to show other data except the "field" column in a table.

Because I trying to do adding,editing and deleting of the "field" through my own website admin portal instead of login to phpmyadmin to do it. Appreciate if have advice on this too.

Thanks[please refer to the picture below for easier understand what I'm asking]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVGQl.png

Comment: Read the answer in the question used as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database_name>' AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>';
```